# Using Android Logcat to display like this

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am new to Android and I am currently trying to understand how to use the logcat well. If you look at this here:

[LinkedIn scribe OAuth library unable to allow access to LinkedIn account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590138/linkedin-scribe-oauth-library-unable-to-allow-access-to-linkedin-account)

This person has logcat print out all system.out.println() to verify that the code works without having to write a full app to run. I was hoping someone could show me how I might be able to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by this:

> without having to write a full app to run.

But the code in that question most probably does not generate those statements without actually running them as an APK.

And then it is just a fact that a line like this:

```
System.out.println("=== LinkedIn's OAuth Workflow ===");
```

Wil behave as if `Log.?` is called. So the way you can do what happens in that question is just put your log-lines (either trough `Log.?` or if you please with `System.out.println`) in your APK. But you need to run it to .. well.. run it :)

Comment: Hi Nannne, thanks for your advice. From the link I provided above, I was under the impression that it wasn't run in an emulator and you're able to verify whether the code is correct through logcat. I guess I am going to have to read more into how these things work. If you have any other suggestions, i'd like to know. thanks!

Comment: well, your IDE (e.g. eclipse) shows real big errors like syntax errors and unreachable code. So when it compiles etc you at least have some measure of 'testing' beforehand. But typing errors means it is run, so you need to actually have something it runs on. I'd say: just follow googles 'hello world' and tutorial, it's quite clear. If you have a running hello world in the emulator, go from there.