# Twitter - retrieve pin code from webview. Android

Tags: android, twitter, webview

Is it possible to somehow retrieve the pin code from WebView in Android while authorising the Twitter?

I've got tutorial example, but to login user need to rewrite the pin code from WebView to app. I just want to pass this and get pin code directly from web.

This is very similar to how it goes on iPhone.

Now I using something like this:

```
public void getTwitter() 
{
      handleEvent.post(new Runnable() 
      {

       @Override
       public void run() 
       {               
            if (oHelper.hasAccessToken()) 
            {

                oHelper.configureOAuth(twitterConnection);
                try 
                {
                     twitterConnection.updateStatus("Hii!!!!");
                } 
                catch (TwitterException e) 
                {
                     Log.d("TWEET", "Error Updating status " + e.getMessage());
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                 try 
                 {
                      twitterConnection.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
                      requestToken = twitterConnection.getOAuthRequestToken("");
                      webViewDialog(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL(), 0);
                 } 
                 catch (TwitterException e) 
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
       }

      });
}
```

then display the webview inside dialog popup:

```
private void webViewDialog(final String authorizationURL, final int type) 
{
      LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
      container.setMinimumWidth(200);
      container.setMinimumHeight(320);
      webView = new WebView(this);

      webView.setMinimumWidth(200);
      webView.setMinimumHeight(380);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      webView.loadUrl(authorizationURL);

      container.addView(webView);
      webDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      webDialog.setView(container).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
      {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         {
             dia = dialog;
              if (type == 0) 
              {
                   twitterPinCodeDialog();
              }

         }
      }).show();
}
```

and in the end prompt user to input pincode:

```
public void twitterPinCodeDialog() 
{
      LinearLayout pinHolder = new LinearLayout(this);
      pinHolder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      final EditText editPinCode = new EditText(this);
      editPinCode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      editPinCode.setHint("Pin Code");
      editPinCode.setWidth(200);
      pinHolder.addView(editPinCode);

      Builder pinBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      pinBuilder.setView(pinHolder).setTitle("Twitter Pin Code Entry")
        .setMessage("Please enter displayed twitter code into the field")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         {
              if (editPinCode.getText().toString() != null && !editPinCode.getText().toString().equals("")) 
              {
                   try 
                   {
                        accessToken = twitterConnection.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,editPinCode.getText().toString());
                        oHelper.storeAccessToken(accessToken);
                        Log.i("Access Token:", accessToken.getToken());
                        Log.i("Access Secret:", accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                        twitterConnection.updateStatus("Tweeted Successfully");
                   } 
                   catch (TwitterException te) 
                   {
                        if (401 == te.getStatusCode()) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            te.printStackTrace();
                        }
                   }
              } 
              else 
              {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Pin code is required",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               dialog.dismiss();    
               dia.dismiss();
               twitterPinCodeDialog();
               }
         }

        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {

           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
           {
                Toast.makeText(context,"To share your news please complete login next time",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
           }
          }).show();
     }
```

I don't even remember from where I took this example. 
But it would be nice to get rid off last dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is quite possible - I don't have my code in front of me, but the process is as follows:

- When you make your twitter authorisation request, you provide it with a callback URL, lets call it callback://myapp.twitter.pin
- Register a URL handler in your manifest for this URL
- When the authorisation is successful, the twitter webpage will redirect the user to your callback URL
- Android will intercept the callback URL and resume your login activity
- You can use your onResume to access the PIN from the uri as I demonstrate in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590138/linkedin-scribe-oauth-library-unable-to-allow-access-to-linkedin-account)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. If you find some example, could you just share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Call the webview activity for authorization as follows.

```
final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                "callback://x-oauthflow-twitter");
        Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                        | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Then retrieve the access token in activity as follows.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null
            && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
        Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
        new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this, consumer, provider, prefs)
                .execute(uri);
        finish();
    }
}

public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
            OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.prefs = prefs;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and
     * oauth_token_secret for future API calls.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        final Uri uri = params[0];
        final String oauth_verifier = uri
                .getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

        try {
            provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

            final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
            edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                    consumer.getTokenSecret());
            edit.commit();

            String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
            // context.startActivity(new Intent(context,
            // MerionActivity.class));

            executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval();

            Log.i(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The activity should be declared in manifest file as follows.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.nppa.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: will u please describe this parameter "x-oauthflow-twitter" what is x what is oauthflow and what to write in place of twitter.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. just give this parameter as such. It is defined like this by the twitter api.